# Learning resources for solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I find docs of solidity very confusing can anyone suggest me some books or online resources for learning solidity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is way too general. We have no idea what parts of the official documentation you find confusing, and therefore we cannot suggest any other material which does not embed the same level of confusion for you. More generally, you should do some Googling first, and come back here with a very specific issue which you still find confusing (i.e., after having searched for it well enough).

Comment: I feel that he's just new to the space so I have given an answer that might help him to get started!!

Answer (score 3):

Getting started​ with Ethereum

- http://ethereum.org/beginners/​
- https://docs.ethhub.io/ethereum-basics/what-is-ethereum/

Start developing

- https://cryptozombies.io/​
- https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop​
- https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/ (advanced)​
- Smart Contract best practices - https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/

**Tutorial:** https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/how-to-build-a-blockchain-app -- This I feel is the best one out there.

Web3js docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/

Solidity docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.13/

Note: Please upvote if it helps!!